# JavaScript read excel from online folder instead of local path, is it possible?

Tags: javascript, excel

I created an HTML/JavaScript webpage that opens an excel file, reads the data, and displays it to the screen. Everything works great when the file path for the excel doc is on my local machine. However, I want to be able to upload the excel doc to a folder online and have the webpage read the data from there. Is that possible? When I change the file path to the online link, the webpage no longer works.

Something else that I tried is saving the excel doc as a webpage and using that link instead, but again, that only works if I use the local link, not the link once I upload it.

Comment: You need to show your actual code if you want suggestions, including how you tried to modify it and exactly what happened when you did that.

Comment: Local file protocols are vastly different from http or ftp, even though your operating system may sometimes present them similarly.
If you want users to be able to enter any URLs you will need to decide whether the URL is sent to the server, and then downloaded by the server (an easy way to expose yourself to various security issues). In this case the question is less about javascript and more about your server-side framework (ASP/PHP/etc...)
As for displaying the spreadsheet, that is a separate question. And should be asked separately.

Comment: If no server-side technologies are there to process the excel file .. than In one word the answer is **NO** ..